# Uninstalling apps in homebrew

Tags: macos, homebrew, matlab

I recently tried to install Matlab from Homebrew for macOS by running `brew install matlab2tikz`. Now, I would like to remove this file. How do I do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can uninstall it by running the command:

`brew uninstall matlab2tikz`

As mentioned in the [other answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/437174/279727), you can look for all the available Homebrew command by reading the manual, which can be accessed by running the following command:

`man brew`

The commmand to uninstall a formula installed via Homebrew is:

`brew uninstall <formula_name>`

Answer (score 0):

`man brew` lists the possible options, including `uninstall`.